# Appengine Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have an Google AppEngine project connected to Google Cloud Sql. 
I found some error on my appengine stackdriver logs. I report the stack java error after. 
I don't found any information about this problem and i don't understand if the problem is the traffic or other.
I wrote to Google Support but the technician tell me to ask a JDO support.
Usually the call works very well but in the day 10/20 times is broken.
I've the same error in different endpoint calls, with different query.

I'm using `JAVA 1.7.0_79` and `appengine sdk 1.9.46` to compile that include `datanucleus version 3.1.3`

Do you have any idea about it?
There is some flag to add a mysql that can help?

```
controller.gorder.XXXEndpoint recuperaDatiAgente: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown. (XXX.java:165)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:421)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:230)
    at controller.gorder.SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.recuperaDatiAgente(SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.java:159)
    at controller.gorder.SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.SyncSpedizioni(SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:169)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:165)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:42)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:145)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:559)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:519)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:489)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Constructor_.newInstance_(Constructor_.java:93)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Constructor_.newInstance(Constructor_.java:44)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1706)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:335)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.release(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.performExecute(SQLQuery.java:364)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractSQLQuery.executeWithArray(AbstractSQLQuery.java:331)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.execute(Query.java:1639)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:221)
    at controller.gorder.SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.recuperaDatiAgente(SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.java:159)
    at controller.gorder.SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.SyncSpedizioni(SituazioneSpedizioniEndpoint.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:169)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:165)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:42)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:145)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:559)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:519)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:489)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The message says clearly enough that MySQL has called some method on "com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept" and it has failed. That is communication with MySQL and presumably Google's JDBC driver?

Comment: Also, you can tell Google "support" that you will not get "JDO support" for that old version of DataNucleus since it says on their website that the only supported versions are v4.1, 4.2 and 5.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)